# MultiLabelBinarizer inverse transfom

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, one-hot-encoding

I am working on a multilabel classification problem using MultiLabelBinarizer to encode the labels. I tried the encoding and decoding processes according to the example given in https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html. The problem is, in the inverse transform,  repeated classes are missing. For clarity, consider an example of multi-label classification problem with five classes and four samples.

```
label = np.array([[2, 3, 4,2,0], [3,1,2,4,2], [0, 1, 3,0,1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
y = mlb.fit_transform(label)`
label_ = mlb.inverse_transform(y)
print(label_)
> [(0, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4), (0, 1, 3), (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)]
```

Note that class number `2` appeared twice in first and second samples, and class number `1` appeared twice in the third sample. But in the decoded version, they appeared once. I guess the model predicts a specific class label once and ignores if it is repeated. But, what if we wanted a one to one mapping between `label` and `label_` in the above example ?  Is there any method we can get back the shape of predicted labels equal to true labels ? any help on this is really appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need the same label twice..?

Comment: @BlackBear my labels are representing independent transmit symbols in wireless communication. Each sample contains independent users symbols. For instance user1 and user2 may have the same symbol , which i represent as the same label. So, I wanted to recover all labels as they belong to different users.

Comment: Feels like it's showing unique values in ascending order